# Can't add Quicksilver keyboard shortcut trigger

Tags: keyboard, quicksilver

I'm setting up a new mac and I can't seem to set the keyboard shortcut to triggers I'm creating, as I've always been able to do before.

I'm able to create the trigger, but then when trying to edit it, after clicking the (i) and attempting to click either the (empty) shortcut box, or the "edit" button next to it, the box flashes "Set Keys" for an instant, but then it disappears and I'm not able to set the shortcut.

See here (you might not be able to see the flash of "Set Keys" because of the gif encoding, but it's there albeit very brief:
[image: can't edit trigger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue.

https://github.com/quicksilver/Quicksilver/issues/2361

It has been fixed and a new version will be released this week sometime.

Until then, you can download an [older version](https://qsapp.com/archives/) to customize the keyboard shortcuts. Once they’re set, you can go back to the latest version, or wait for the next update.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with Quicksilver yesterday to give it a whirl for fun and I encountered the same issue. This is an issue with the software itself, not with the Macintosh OS.

Quicksilver is available as an opensource software if you would like to perhaps fix it, or raise the issue on their repository. I was going to but I didn't have the time to look through the 300+ issues already submitted to see if someone else had already.

https://github.com/quicksilver/Quicksilver

Quicksilver has always been full of bugs. Perhaps try Alfred, Launchbar, or another Spotlight alternative.

EDIT: However if you really want to use Quicksilver for some reason, you could clone the repository and checkout a previous version of the project and compile the application locally.